# (Python) How do I get the weather icon from weatherapi.com?

Tags: python, tkinter, weather-api

I am trying to make a weather app with Python and Tkinter. I am using the weather api from weatherapi.com. I have pretty much everything but the icon, I don't know how to get the icon url from the .json file and update the icon when searching at a different city or place.

here is the image of the json file where the current condition icon is:
[image: This is where the current condition icon url is]

Here is the createFrameInfo  code in the view.py:

```
#the information of the current condition the text that says "image" is a place holder for the actual icon
def _createFrameInfo(self):
        self.frameInfo = Frame(self.mainframe)
        
        labelTemp = Label(self.frameInfo, textvariable=self.varTemp)
        labelLocation = Label(self.frameInfo, textvariable= self.varLocation)
        labelIcon = Label(self.frameInfo, text = 'image')

        labelTemp.pack(pady = 5)
        labelLocation.pack(pady = 5)
        labelIcon.pack(pady = 5)
        self.frameInfo.pack()
```

Here is a bit of code from weather.py

```
# The pass is there so the app can run without having an error.
    def getConditionIcon(self):
        pass
```

Here is the github of the all the codes: https://github.com/EasyCanadianGamer/Python-Weather-App

I checked the docs and yet there was not a clear explanation of how to get the icon url and updating it. Here is the Weatherapi docs: https://www.weatherapi.com/docs/

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here.

Comment: You get the URI for the icon the same way you get the text (`"Partly cloudy"`). Where is your code that tries to get any information out of the json?

Comment: The code is in the model/weather.py but here is a paste bin of the code that gets the info from the json: https://pastebin.com/vxm5G95v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the icon URL like how you get the *condition text* and use `requests.get()` to get the icon data:

```py
def getConditionIcon(self):
    condition = self.getCurrentData("condition")
    icon_url = f"http:{condition['icon']}"
    try:
        icon_data = requests.get(icon_url).content
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        icon_data = None
    return icon_data
```

Then you can pass the icon data to `tkinter.PhotoImage()` to create an image object:

```py
weather = Weather(...)  # pass the location you want
image = tkinter.PhotoImage(data=weather.getConditionIcon())
```

Note that if the icon image is not PNG image, you may need to use `Pillow` module to convert the icon data to image.